# How do I resize (smaller) baby bootie crochet pattern?

Tags: crocheting, pattern-drafting

I am crocheting a set of baby booties for an infant using this pattern:

http://lacycrochet.blogspot.ca/2014/01/crochet-baby-booties-size-0-6-months.html

I need the booties to be about 3/4 the size for which the pattern is written.  I am using a #3 yarn and a 3.5 mm (E) hook.

How do i adjust the pattern to accomplish this?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to use a smaller hook. You might also need thinner yarn so your booties aren't too stiff/thick.

If you don't have a smaller hook, you'll have to change the pattern. It's hard to tell you exactly how without having crocheted the pattern because a bootie has a fairly complicated shape. One strategy you can try is to make one bootie as written to get a better idea of the construction. It would be a fast job since it's a small item, and once you've completed it you might find you'll have a better idea of how to make it smaller.